# Is it possible to replace double quote " character in a string via Spring DSL?

Tags: regex, apache-camel, transform

Is it possible to replace double quote " character  in a string via Spring DSL? I have a name space in the xml which I need to strip before sending to another end point.

To remove below string from xml

```
xsi:schemaLocation="xxxxx"
```

I tried using simple language , it ran but it didn't replace the quote

```
<route>
<from uri="file:src/xmldata?noop=true"/>
<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>                                 
<setBody>
<simple>
{body.replaceAll("xsi:schemaLocation="xxxxx"","")}
</simple>
</setBody>  .  .  </route>`
```

Comment: Logically thinking, you need to assign a new value o body, try `{body = body.replaceAll("xsi:schemaLocation=\"xxxxx\"","")}`

Comment: Thanks, I have big xml inside body and need to retain that, only namespaces needs to be removed as informatica (consumer of my message) doesn't support it.  For some reason the escape \" isn't working either . I also tried &quot; and that didn't work.  However for similar req I was able to replace < and > symbol using  &lt; and &gt;

Comment: Perhaps, to match a " you can use `\x22` or `\u0022`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hats off Wiktor. It worked like a charm. Thanks a ton. I now understand java uses unicode

Comment: I can post that solution myself, but since you posted an answer, let it be. Was it `{body.replaceAll("xsi:schemaLocation=\u0022xxxxx\u0022","")}` or `{body=body.replaceAll("xsi:schemaLocation=\u0022xxxxx\u0022","")}`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. I am new to the stack flow group.  This one worked. `{body.replaceAll("xsi:schemaLocation=\u0022xxxxx\u0022","")}`

Comment: If anyone posts an answer, and you accept your own answer, you will lose reputation points. When someone helps you, just ask to post the suggestion that worked as an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew great. I deleted mine. Please try posting now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, when there is a problem with regex matching double or single quotes, it is suffice to use a hex representation of the character: `\u0022` (or `\x22` depending on the language/engine).

So, use

```
{body.replaceAll("xsi:schemaLocation=\u0022xxxxx\u0022","")}
                                     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^
```

Note that a single quote can be matched with `\u0027` (or `\x27`). There is a great site I use to find out hex codes, here is [a link to the *Unicode code converter*](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/).

Answer (score 0):

In all the examples please note: `${body.}`, not `{body.}` (that fow those who just looking for the XML replacement example)